# Multiple Line Insert: Как вставить результат запроса в таблицу?

Tags: postgresql, sql

Есть таблица из 2х колонок.
Хочу заполнить ее одним запросом.
Первая колонка есть значения одной колонки из другой таблицы.
Вторая колонка есть некая константа.

То есть надо:

- считать набор значений из Таблицы 2
- объединить это с Константой
- вставить это одним запросом в Таблицу 1

Это возможно?

Postgresql 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде:

```
INSERT INTO tb1 (col1_FromTb2, col2_withConstVal) 
    SELECT tb2.val1, 'my_const' FROM tb2
    WHERE tb2.field = 'need_val';
```